# How to disable freemarker caching in Spring MVC

Tags: caching, spring-mvc, freemarker

I'm using spring mvc v3 with freemarker views and cannot disable caching.
I tried by setting cache to false in viewResolver element in (spring-servlet.xml) but didn't work.

Basically what I'd like to the do some changes in freemarker and see these changes in the browser with refresh only (w/o restarting the application)

Any hints how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

In my XML the following was successful:

```
<bean id="freemarkerMailConfiguration" class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean">
    <property name="templateLoaderPaths" value="classpath:emailtemplates/task,classpath:emailtemplates/user"/>
    <!-- Activate the following to disable template caching -->
    <property name="freemarkerSettings" value="cache_storage=freemarker.cache.NullCacheStorage" />
</bean>
```

This is my mail config, but the freemarkerConfig should be interesting four you, too.

Answer (score 3):

I dont use to configure freemarker with **xml** configurations but with `@Configuration` annotated classes; cause i rather the Spring-Boot´ style. So you can disable the freemarker´s cache like this:

```
@Bean
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer() throws IOException, TemplateException
{
    FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer()
    {

        @Override
        protected void postProcessConfiguration(freemarker.template.Configuration config) throws IOException, TemplateException
        { 
            ClassTemplateLoader classTplLoader = new ClassTemplateLoader(context.getClassLoader(), "/templates"); 
            ClassTemplateLoader baseMvcTplLoader = new ClassTemplateLoader(FreeMarkerConfigurer.class, ""); //TODO tratar de acceder a spring.ftl de forma directa
            MultiTemplateLoader mtl = new MultiTemplateLoader(new TemplateLoader[]
            { 
                classTplLoader,
                baseMvcTplLoader
            });
            config.setTemplateLoader(mtl);
            config.setCacheStorage(new NullCacheStorage()); 
        }
    };
    configurer.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8"); 
    configurer.setPreferFileSystemAccess(false);
    return configurer;
}
```

The key is in:

> config.setCacheStorage(new NullCacheStorage());

But you can also use this instruction instead:

```
config.setTemplateUpdateDelayMilliseconds(0);
```

It should work for you.

Answer (score 3):

In application.properties:

```
spring.freemarker.cache=false
```

Answer (score 2):

As defined by the [manual](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_config_templateloading.html#pgui_config_templateloading_caching) :

> If you change the template file, then FreeMarker will re-load and
>   re-parse the template automatically when you get the template next
>   time. However, since checking if the file has been changed can be time
>   consuming, there is a Configuration level setting called ``update
>   delay''. This is the time that must elapse since the last checking for
>   a newer version of a certain template before FreeMarker will check
>   that again. **This is set to 5 seconds by default. If you want to see
>   the changes of templates immediately, set it to 0.**

After searching around, the configuration key was in the [freemarker.template.Configuration javadocs, at the setSetting(key, value) method](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/api/freemarker/template/Configuration.html#setSetting%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).
So, in short, just set the config **template_update_delay** to **0** for immediate change detection.

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
  <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/ftl/"/>
  <property name="freemarkerSettings">
        <props>
            <prop key="template_update_delay">0</prop>
            <prop key="default_encoding">UTF-8</prop>
        </props>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: the property name is `templateLoaderPaths`, you miss `s`. Does spring convert it to `templateLoaderPaths` smartly?

Comment: It got both templateLoaderPath and templateLoaderPaths. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/freemarker/FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.html#setTemplateLoaderPath-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the [FreeMarker documentation](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_config_templateloading.html#pgui_config_templateloading_caching), which contains some hints regarding how to influence template caching at the FreeMarker `Configuration` level. I'm not sure if you have access to the FreeMarker `Configuration` object from inside Spring MVC, but if you have, then the documentation page mentioned above could point you towards a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I wasted the last two days (note entirely for this project) trying to disable the cache. It turns out I have the two options antiJARLocking and antiResourceLocking set in my context.xml. Then the templates will ALWAYS be cached

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem which I could solve only by implementing a custom template loader. Here is the working code:

```
protected void init() throws Exception {
    freemarkerConfig = new Configuration();
    freemarkerConfig.setObjectWrapper(ObjectWrapper.DEFAULT_WRAPPER);
    freemarkerConfig.setTemplateLoader(new CacheAgnosticTemplateLoader(new DefaultResourceLoader(), pdfTemplatePath));
}

protected static class CacheAgnosticTemplateLoader extends SpringTemplateLoader {
    public CacheAgnosticTemplateLoader(ResourceLoader resourceLoader, String templateLoaderPath) {
        super(resourceLoader, templateLoaderPath);
    }

    @Override
    public long getLastModified(Object templateSource) {
        // disabling template caching
        return new Date().getTime();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the recently released FreeMarker version 2.3.17, a legal and simpler way to do it has appeared: `freemarker.cache.NullCacheStorage`.

Comment: Any example on how to set NullCacheStorage using only configuration?